# Combining data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe like this:

```
name code code2 region 
A    1     2     5 
B    3     4     5 
C    5     6     6 
A    7     8     5
```

And I need to group data by name and region? and then save both codes in one column, so output will be like:

```
name     codes        region 
A    [1, 2], [7, 8]      5 
B       [3, 4]           5 
C       [5, 6]           6
```

I came up with this:

```
df['codes'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(np.append(x['code'], x['code2'])), axis=1)
df = df.groupby(['name', 'region'])
```

But after "groupby" I can not work with  df and don`t know how I can continue ?

Comment: after grouping df won't be a DataFrame but a DataFrameGroupBy. You can iterate it with ```for key, frame in df: pass```

Answer (score 1):

try `pd.melt` with `unstack`

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["name", "region"]).groupby(["name", "region", "variable"])[
    "value"
].agg(list).unstack(-1).agg(list,axis=1).to_frame('codes')

print(df1)

                        codes
name region                  
A    5       [[1, 7], [2, 8]]
B    5             [[3], [4]]
C    6             [[5], [6]]
```

---

Don't recommend, but if you want your target output you'll have to convert your lists into strings.

```
df_str = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["name", "region"]).groupby(["name", "region", "variable"])[
    "value"
].agg(list).unstack(-1).astype(str).agg(','.join,axis=1).to_frame('codes')


print(df_str)

                     codes
name region               
A    5       [1, 7],[2, 8]
B    5             [3],[4]
C    6             [5],[6]
```

---

Or a more simple solution:

note level 1-0 refers to the index that you've set - Name and Region.

```
df.set_index(['name', 'region']).agg(list, axis=1).groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list)

name  region
A     5         [[1, 2], [7, 8]]
B     5                 [[3, 4]]
C     6                 [[5, 6]]
```